Type-state pattern in C#
I want to implement the typestate pattern in C#. I've tried something like:
interface Open {}
interface Closed {}

abstract class Foo<T> { }

class Bar<T> where T: Closed { }
class Bar<T> where T: Open { }

as well as other permutations, but they all end up with the compiler complaining. This particular example gives (via https://www.programiz.com/csharp-programming/online-compiler/):
/tmp/qmk1tTLHWG.cs(12,11): error CS0101: The namespace 'baz' already contains a definition for 'Bar'
/tmp/qmk1tTLHWG.cs(11,11): error CS0265: Partial declarations of 'Bar<T>' have inconsistent constraints for type parameter 'T'


I don't know enough about C#'s type system to know what will actually work, and I can't find much documentation about how to do this. Is it possible to implement the type state pattern? I found Adam's blog however he doesn't actually implement the type state pattern as shown in 1, which is what I'd like to do if possible.
Ideally I'd like something like
struct Closed { }; 
struct Open { };

class Foo<T> {
    // functions applicable to Foo's in both the Closed and Open states
}

class Foo<Closed> {
    // functions applicable to Foo's in just the Open state
}

class Foo<Open> {
    // functions applicable to Foo's in just the Open state
}


"which is what I'd like to do if possible" - it's not. At least not as it is implemented in the first snippet.

Can you make base class Foo and two subclasses FooClosed : Foo and FooOpen : Foo?

I'd prefer not to make FooClosed and FooOpen if the language has support for this, especially since the state machine I'm trying to implement is quite complex and would likely have many different variations of FooXYZ

Typestate is an idiom, not a design pattern. It's a language-specific solution to the problem of creating a state machine with compile-time checking. Functional langauges like F# would use discriminated unions for this. C# doesn't have DUs yet. You can use pattern matching to get code similar to F#, or you can use other patterns to have the compiler verify all valid transitions have been matched.

Is the typestate pattern just a variation of a fluent interface?

@beyarkay what's the actual state machine? You posted what you expect the implementation to look like, not the state machine itself. If you want type safety, you could add an F# library to your project and implement the state machine in just a few lines that can be reused by the rest of the project. Check this implementation of a 3-state machine for example

Or are you looking for something like this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/KVUUdd ?

@Fildor that looks like Jonathan's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/78677770/14555505), which I've accepted.

@beyarkay I was typing the fiddle and comment before I refreshed the page ... mind one difference: in my fiddle, I have explicit interface implementations to hide the state-specific methods on direct Foo references.

@DavidG the typestate pattern lets you define dependencies between states amongst other things, I recommend reading the linked blog post for details.

@beyarkay the linked blog post talks about API return types, similar to how LINQ operators return different types of IQueryables that only allow specific operations. You can't apply ThenByDescending on any IQueryable, it only works on an IOrderedQueryable that's only returned by OrderBy. That's not the same as a type-safe state machine.

@beyarkay That Foo class can be cast explicitly to the wrong type, bypassing type checking. Someone could call Open succesfully on an "open" object this way. If the methods were converted to extension methods though, casting Foo to IOpen or IClosed would be impossible.

@Fildor The explicit implementations aren't really necessary if Foo cannot be instantiated directly.

I would also create FooOpen and FooClosed, and make all of those things internal so they cannot even be seen by an external project. That way, callers only deal with the public interfaces and can't go around casting things to invalid states.

@JohnathanBarclay Right. Just pointed out the diff to OP. That's a thing, I'd do in Fluent-APIs.

You should model this via interfaces, but there only needs to be a single class.
An example:
interface IOpen
{
    IClosed Close();
}

interface IClosed
{
    IOpen Open();
}

class Foo : IOpen, IClosed
{
    public IOpen Open()
    {
        return this;
    }

    public IClosed Close()
    {
        return this;
    }
}

var foo = new Foo();
var open = foo.Open();

var closed = open.Close(); // Only Close() is allowed on an open foo
closed.Open(); // Only Open() is allowed on an closed foo


You can extend this by forcing a default state on Foo using a factory method:
class Foo : IOpen, IClosed
{
    private Foo() // Prevent manual instantiation (using new)
    { }

    public static IClosed Create() // Return closed by default
    {
        return new Foo();
    }

    public IOpen Open()
    {
        return this;
    }

    public IClosed Close()
    {
        return this;
    }
}

var closed = Foo.Create();
var open = closed.Open(); // Only Open() is allowed by default

